# Jira Plug-in ScriptRunner Escalation Service: Post request will continue to return cache response

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm a beginner using ScriptRunner and Groovy.
I have a post request that returns an array of string. I thought it was working fine until I compared it with my Javascript post request response. (same endpoint with same param data)
How do I confirm I'm getting cache response? or how do I make sure I dont' get cache response? (if it is server-side cache, shouldn't I get the same response through Javascript call as well?)

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput( true );
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write( postData );   

def statusArrayString = new StringBuffer();
def rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

def line;
while((line=rd.readLine()) !=null) {
    statusArrayString.append(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTTP RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#page-54) the POST requests are not cached if you do not specifically set specific headers. And usually you don't.

But if you want to be sure, just add some dummy query string (e.g. timestamp) to the end of URL.